# awk. Rounding the result of division

Tags: awk, division

I have a test file:

```
user1   230230  1970
user2   313221  1978
user5   212334  1924
user3   313221  1987
user4   212345  1999
user3   123456  1983
user5   121212  1903
user2   234234  1992
user3   124690  1922
user5   092343  1945
```

when i run this script:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.2f"}{user_arr[$1]+=$2;user_arr_count[$1]+=1;}END{for (el in user_arr) {n=user_arr[el]/user_arr_count[el];print n}}' test
```

I get result

```
230230
273727.50
187122.33
212345
141963
```

but if i run

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.2f"}{user_arr[$1]+=$2;user_arr_count[$1]+=1;}END{for (el in user_arr) {n=user_arr[el]/user_arr_count[el];print n" "el}}' test
```

I get rounds value:

```
230230 user1
273728 user2
187122 user3
212345 user4
141963 user5
```

why the result is rounded?
Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first script you are printing the value `n` and `awk` knows to treat it as a number however in the second script you are printing `n" "el` which is treated as a string because you are using string concatenation. What you want to do instead is `print n,el`.

I would write the script like:

```
$ awk '{u[$1]+=$2;c[$1]+=1}END{for(i in u)print i,u[i]/c[i]}' OFMT="%.2f" file
user1 230230
user2 273727.50
user3 187122.33
user4 212345
user5 141963
```

Comment: WOW!! yes! Exactly! Tank you very-very ))